# Javascript cross-scripts variable values

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

I think I am missing something here, but I really can't see what it is. Shouldn't a variable declared outside a function be available throughout the whole page? What I'm trying here I have already seen before, so I guess the basic idea should work. In this case I always get the alert to tell me "false", so I guess it always enters if, thus skipUserDataEntry has undefined value instead of true. Hope someone can help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     skipUserDataEntry = true;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        Ext.onReady(function () {
         if (typeof skipUserDataEntry == "undefined")
      var skipUserDataEntry = false;
         alert (skipUserDataEntry);
        }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of problems. Your global variable is fine. But, any variable declared inside a function() **ANYWHERE** will be scoped for that **WHOLE** function.

This means your row reading `var skipUserDataEntry = false;` is actually declaring a new variable `skipUserDataEntry` for the function scope, shadowing the global one.

Remove the `var` and you will only look at the global scoped variable.

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {
     if (typeof skipUserDataEntry == "undefined")
       skipUserDataEntry = false;
     alert (skipUserDataEntry);
    });
```

Secondly you're missing an end parenthesis.

Comment: The missing parenthesis was a typo, since I have other things ongoing on the Ext.onReady but didn't paste them. Thanks for the help, the var works.